# Como fazer meu script executar com dois cliques um comando que contem sudo?

Tags: shell-script, mono, linux

Tenho um script bem simples, similar a este:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Seleciono o diretório onde se encontra o arquivo para execução 
cd '/home/vmi/Área de Trabalho/TesteComandosNoLinux'
#Executo meu software
mono my-program.exe
```

Descobri que preciso que meu software seja executado como administrador para que   algumas funcionalidades funcionem corretamente.

Esse script é [executado com dois cliques](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows) para deixar o mais amigável possível com os usuários.

Gostaria de manter a execução com dois cliques, porém não consegui criar (ou encontrar um script) assim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que fiz foi editar o arquivo /etc/sudoers

Add no final do arquivo:

`user ALL=(ALL) ALL
user ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:path/do/meu-segundo-Script.sh
user ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:path/do/mono
user ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:path/do/meu/executável`

É exigido a senha do usuário para que meu script seja executado com `./meu-segundo-Script.sh`.Isso não acontece quando o script é executado com `sudo ./meu-segundo-Script.sh`, mas não encontrei maneira equivalente de fazer `sudo ./meu-segundo-Script.sh` com dois cliques.

A resolução foi criar um script que chama meu script que não precisa de senha ao executar o comando sudo.

meu-primeiro-Script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd '/home/vmi/Área de Trabalho/MinhaPasta'
sudo meu-segundo-Script.sh
```

meu-segundo-Script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mono my-program.exe
```

Comment: Maravilha. Valeu por compartilhar :/

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Altere o grupo do seu bash para sudo.
Ao fazer isso irá rodar com poderes de administrador.
No Linux Mint por exemplo é possível fazer clicando com botão direito e propriedades, na aba "Permissões".
Se preferir via comando:

> chown [opções] [novo_proprietário] [:novo_grupo] arquivo

Exemplo (no terminal):

> chown valmor:sudo arquivo.sh

Irá mudar as propriedades. Caso precise de poderes lembre-se de usar sudo para aplicar a mudança

> sudo chown valmor:sudo arquivo.sh

Comment: como faço isso ?

Comment: complementei a resposta. Da uma olhada!

Comment: Cara, eu fiz isso add o script para root e não funcionou. Farei novamente por desencargo de consciência

Comment: Ficou pertencente ao grupo sudo?
Ao dar um ls -la as propriedades devem estar similar a isso:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 valmor sudo 149 mai  8  2019 valmor_emulador.sh

Comment: Acabei de fazer novamente. O comando foi executado como descrito. Ao executar o ls -la obtenho -rwxrwxrwx spectrum sudo 44 Nov 22 18:20 VMIS.sh.

Comment: Mas ainda não funcionou.

Comment: Verdade, só da certo quando manda executar no terminal, então aparece a confirmação :/

Comment: Vou mostrar uma resolução que encontrei como opção de resposta. Ainda não é onde quero chegar então não marcarei como resolvido. Mas pode ajudar alguém a me ajudar.

Comment: Agora fiquei em duvida se devo completar a pergunta ou postar como resposta